# Maven does not find Java compiler despite having set JAVA_HOME

Tags: maven

I've set

```
stefan@stefan:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

(I've also tried `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`)

but if I run `mvn clean install` on my project I see

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) on project shared: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

The respective entry in the pom.xml for the `maven-compiler-plugin` is set to Java 8:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't know what I am missing out here. How can I tell Maven where the compiler is?

Comment: Have you set M2_HOME?

Comment: @yorammi No, I can't remember that I ever had to set that. Do I have to set it?

Comment: yes, I think you should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following,

1. On console, run java -version and see if it works fine.
2. Run javac -version and see if it works

If any of the above does not work, it means

1. Your installation is not correct. Run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` again.
2. There is a broken previous java installation. Step 1 should again solve this problem.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`. It's already installed.

Comment: I've downloaded and extracted OpenJDK 11 and set JAVA_HOME pointing to it. After that Maven wasn't able to find compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Set JAVA_HOME to JDK instead of JRE.

Comment: It is set to  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `JDK_PATH/bin` to the `PATH`.